# Please help identify this icon of a young man holding a small cross

Tags: iconography

Hello I would like help to identify this icon photograph. It is Greek Orthodox icon with a man holding a cross. [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So interesting! I thought it was a Greek Orthodox saint since my mother-in-law was from Cyprus. My family is from Russia! So nice to have a Russian icon in our home. God Bless!

Answer (score 1):

[images.google.com](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiu02qsdHn-eD2pXzBVqGIouSiO8E8LiJPMlyowntr4w_1lg859XxjYYhGqZkx4DycCk6NNk0uhbdIqN0oK1htHNPkdzTgs0ZO-nqJQSjZDYOku-_1IFFBNXo8oYBTKyNrpB7BwY5Evx1Bte04xVFCYlgduzUPY06wTEO0oZoWR7ITIB31_1gg3XRZVATPoXmp-tXb1VYSKRUzKbQN6D1s2PTlhdDVMeJ7tCqbGfoZYlHNX3MH9R1CxkyGKO3FfE3BAa0HEVvsxD8CBJnYG69d3miiPNBqzNzNKFvVQ2NhbMh0MDQMQf26cthy064gPv9UlGjAJgiN2w0KdOaWUvejqv26oJsOezA&hl=en) led to this [orthodoxtimes](https://orthodoxtimes.com/feast-of-saint-john-the-russian-and-confessor/) which seems to indicate this is Saint John the Russian<sup>1</sup>

> the Holy Confessor John the Russian was born in Little Russia around 1690

<sub>1 [Wiki: John the Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_the_Russian): many external links at bottom of page contain similar images</sub>

<sub>Many of the links are not in English. the above article has the image but doesn't specifically state who is in the picture, I'm assuming the content is about the image</sub>

Comment: You might add that [John the Russian - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_the_Russian) has several external links at the bottom to sites that contain very similar images.